# Counter-example to $\nabla^2 f =0 \implies \nabla \times \nabla f =\vec 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, examples-counterexamples, laplacian

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> "Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $\nabla^2 f =0$, then $\nabla \cdot \nabla f =0$ and $\nabla \times \nabla f =\vec 0$". If the previous statement is true, prove it. If it's false, give a counter-example.

Here I'm using the following definitions:
$$
\nabla f := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \boldsymbol{\hat\imath} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \boldsymbol{\hat\jmath} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\boldsymbol{\hat k}
$$
$$
\nabla^2f := \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 y} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 z}
$$
$$
\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \left(\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z}\right)  \boldsymbol{\hat\imath} + \left(\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}\right)  \boldsymbol{\hat\jmath} + \left(\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}\right) \boldsymbol{\hat k}
$$
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} :=  \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x}
$$
where $\mathbf{A} := A_x \boldsymbol{\hat\imath} + A_y \boldsymbol{\hat\jmath}+ A_z\boldsymbol{\hat k}$.

---

Using the definitions above I've managed to show that $\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f$. This covers the first part of the question.

However, while trying to expand $\nabla  \times \nabla f$ I get
$$
\nabla  \times \nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial z} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial y}\right)  \boldsymbol{\hat\imath} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial x} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial z}\right)  \boldsymbol{\hat\jmath} + \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\right) \boldsymbol{\hat k}
$$
If I say that the mixed partials are equal, then this would conclude the proof. However, it is my understanding that the mixed partials are equal *only if* the function $f$ satisfies [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Schwarz%27s_theorem).

---

My question came about because using the definitions above, I think I can have a function $f$ where the second partial derivatives *exist* and they add up to $0$ *without* the function $f$ satisfying Schwarz's theorem. This would then mean (if I understand correctly) that a counter-example to the statement could exist.

I tried modifying the function $g(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq 0$ and outputs $0$ if $(x,y) = 0$, such that the modified function $f$ would be one where $\nabla^2 f =0$. I did this because I know this function $g(x,y)$ *fails* Schwarz's theorem, so I thought I could use it to construct a counter-example, but the only function I could come up with was $f(x,y) =\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}  = 0$, which defeated the purpose.

Does anyone know an *explicit* counter-example to $\nabla^2 f =0 \implies \nabla  \times \nabla f =\vec 0$? Or can anyone tell me if I'm missing something that makes the statement true? Any and all help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I remember you asking clarification for this a few days ago. The resolution here is that it is not possible. There is a theorem which states that all solutions to the Laplace equation are smooth (i.e. infinitely differentiable) so Schwarz's theorem will always be satisfied. In the future, I hope the lesson you'll take from this is do not waste your time. Your perseverance is admirable, however, your time is valuable and going down rabbit holes like this is not worth it, as many grad students can attest.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me anywhere where I could find a proof of the theorem you mention?

Comment: Any intro graduate level text on PDEs will have in their Laplace equation section. Usually the logical flow is that $\Delta u = 0 \iff u$ satisfies the mean value property, then the mean value property implies that $u$ is analytic, hence smooth.